# error in gradle android studio

Tags: android, gradle

i I'm with this error in gradle
please help me

```html
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Comment: Go to the 'Build options` and select `Clean project` or `Rebuild project` in the Android studio

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in your build.gradle inside default config and build

```
 aaptOptions {
            cruncherEnabled = false
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"
```